# How to implement Intents for seamless navigation

Tags: android

1. I implemented 30+ intents in my app, which I use to switch activity.
2. But I'm getting a 0.5s delay and glitch while opening the activity.
3. What is an intent filter do I need to use that.
4. How to declare the activity in the manifest
5. Below the code is how I declare activity.

> Manifest

```html
 <activity android:name=".loc" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

> java

```
TextView textView9 = findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    textView9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent page2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),page3.class);
            startActivity(page2);
```

Comment: The code you posted is unlikely to be the source of the problem. What is more likely is that you're performing too much work in your onCreate/onResume methods.

Comment: I recently had a crash at this line super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);, how do I recover from this? @m0skit0

Comment: So is it slow or is it crashing?

Comment: I think the problem is " E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Embed config is not supported in RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.". Is there any fix? thanks @m0skit0